# Is there a way to get a photo by photoId in Flickr.Net?

Tags: c#, flickr

I have nearly all bits of my Flickr app worked out but I'm stumped by this. I can upload a photo using UploadPicture and this will return the created photo's photoId. But now I'd like to have the full Photo object for that id. For the life of me I can't figure out how to get that as there doesn't seem to be a GetPhoto method. The consequence is that after a picture upload I have to download all pictures to find the one uploaded. That's a waste of bandwidth and Flickr's resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.

From the Flickr API:

> **[flickr.photos.getInfo](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html)**
>
> Get information about a photo. The calling user must have permission
> to view the photo.

After digging around the FlickerNet [documentation](https://flickrnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#FlickrNet/Flickr_Photos.cs), I found their implementation for it:

> **FlickrNet.Flickr.PhotosGetInfo**
>
> - public PhotoInfo PhotosGetInfo(string photoId, string secret){...}
> - public PhotoInfo PhotosGetInfo(string photoId) {...}

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. One issue though: it doesn't return the full photo object. I find it really strange in Flickr's architecture that you can get a collection of X, but not a single instance of X by its ID. The PhotoInfo is just an abstract and doesn't contain nearly as many fields as the Photo object.

Comment: I've taken a look at the PhotoInfo class and it seems that there are many members to the Class. What info is missing when you call PhotosGetInfo?
https://flickrnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#FlickrNet/PhotoInfo.cs